# error in Pkg.add("Plots") connection reset by peer

Tags: installation, julia

I'm installing Julia for the first time on Ubuntu WSL2 and I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to automatically download/install artifact 'JpegTurbo' from sources listed in '/mnt/d/username/julia_pack/packages/JpegTurbo_jll/eOw3k/Artifacts.toml'.
Sources attempted:
- https://pkg.julialang.org/artifact/22a0f38792d33b65e35189101e60e1fab0a56030
    Error: RequestError: ssl_handshake returned - mbedTLS: (-0x0050) NET - Connection was reset by peer while requesting https://pkg.julialang.org/artifact/22a0f38792d33b65e35189101e60e1fab0a56030
- https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/JpegTurbo_jll.jl/releases/download/JpegTurbo-v2.1.91+0/JpegTurbo.v2.1.91.x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
    Error: RequestError: ssl_handshake returned - mbedTLS: (-0x0050) NET - Connection was reset by peer while requesting https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/JpegTurbo_jll.jl/releases/download/JpegTurbo-v2.1.91+0/JpegTurbo.v2.1.91.x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
```

Lots of other packages were installed correctly; but I don't know what is wrong with this one. I can type "https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/JpegTurbo_jll.jl/releases/download/JpegTurbo-v2.1.91+0/JpegTurbo.v2.1.91.x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz" into my browser and it downloads it correctly. I wonder what's going wrong with Julia.

I have proxies configured for Git, which I presume Julia uses in the background.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: WSL2 has its own network configuration. Hence if something works in the browser it might still not works in WSL2. Perhaps try in the WSL2 terminal `wget https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/JpegTurbo_jll.jl/releases/download/JpegTurbo-v2.1.91+0/JpegTurbo.v2.1.91.x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz` and see what happens

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  wget says `Proxy tunneling failed: Proxy Authentication RequiredUnable to establish SSL connection.`  curl seems to fail with no output.

Comment: OK. So it seems you need to sort out the WSL2 network. The network on WLS2 occasionally crashes - I have seen many tutorials on how to repair it. (and this is Windows issue not Julia issue). You need to sort it out until wget can reach internet on your WSL2 machine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot spend time repairing the WSL2 network. I've decided to take the easy way out and install Julia on a machine without a firewall/proxy.